# SQL SERVER Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 only on EXE file

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

SO 
on my server i have sql server 2008 R2
I have got 3 sites

All of them works good and can connect to my db using the same connection string :

```
 <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString=
                                "Data Source=(local);
                                Initial Catalog=my_db;
                                Persist Security Info=True;
                                User ID=my_user;
                                Password=mypass"
                                providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Problem is:

I have another windows form applications that use the same connection string

As the sites but for this iam getting

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

any ideas ?

Comment: The windows exe is also on the same machine as the DB server?

Comment: Did you enabled client protocols (TCP/IP, Named Pipes, VIA) in SQL Server Configuration Manager?